form_state doesn't contains input values injected from script
I have a little problem with forms.
I built a "contact" custom form extending FormBase to display a contact form the user can fill and send.
In particular case, this form must embed a  that add new fields dynamically to the page. The new fields are on the page, and when I submit the form, values are passed to the request :
// Here are the standard form fields...
civility: 1
firstname: Firstname
lastname: Lastname
country: CH
street: The street
zip: 1000
city: City
phone: +41790000000
mail: test@gmail.com
hidden_subject: Request for object
message: lorem ipsum

// Here are the dynamically added fields...
startDateDisplay: 06/07/2024
endDateDisplay: 06/21/2024
startDate: 2024-06-07 12:00:00
endDate: 2024-06-21 11:59:00
capacity: 5
capacityAdults: 2
capacityChildren: 3
capacityBabies: 1

This is the "payload" I can see in the network pane of my dev panel.
So values are sent to the backend. But when I try to retrieve theses dynamically added values, they are not present in the $form_state instance.
Ok, I can maybe imagine that before calling my submit form handler, some checks are done to exclude values that doesn't exists into the form. But in this case, what can I do to include it ?
If anyone has a suggestion it would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.
